# How does $\psi(x) =\exp(\frac{iq}{\hbar}\int^xA(x')\cdot dx')\phi(x)$ remove the gauge field for a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, gauge-invariance

In what sense does writing $$\psi(x) =\exp(\frac{iq}{\hbar}\int^xA(x')\cdot dx')\phi(x)$$ "formally remove the gauge field" for a free particle in the Hamiltonian $$H\psi=\frac{1}{2m}(-i\hbar\nabla -qA)^2\psi~?$$ How is this supposed to work?

See section 1.3.2 of these lecture notes for full context http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm.html

Comment: Substitute the "new wavefunction" \psi into the schrodinger equation and see the magic of all the A's dropping out. \phi therefore satisfies the free equation